# Quote trigger_recollect never passing to 0?

Tags: magento2, quote

Is it "normal" that when i modify my quote manually through phpmyadmin, i put "trigger_recollect" to 1, then i reload my cart, it's staying to 0 ?

*Note : I'm trying to modify my product final prices through observers/plugin/whatever...*

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is normal. `trigger_recollect` is used as a flag that is unset once the totals are recollected. This happens in the quote model's `_afterLoad()` method:

```
//Code from Magento\Quote\Model\Quote

protected function _afterLoad()
{
    // collect totals and save me, if required
    if (1 == $this->getData('trigger_recollect')) {
        $this->collectTotals()->save();
    }
    return parent::_afterLoad();
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Why having a field in database if it never set to 0 ?

Comment: I believe that it's being set to 0 somewhere in the collectTotals()->save() process, but I'm not exactly sure. I'll try to look later...

Answer (score 3):

I also noticed that it will never be set to 0 while debugging.

In my case, it seems to be the root of a problem some customers have: they experience a timeout when they want to add a product to a cart. I raised an issue on GitHub to let the magento developers know: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9580